# Как загрузить файлы на удаленный хост с помощью rsync?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

Хочу повторить действия автора из [статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/317732/). На одном из этапов требуется загрузить файлы на удаленные хосты с помощью утилиты rsync. Можете подсказать как это делается? Какое значение должно быть у REMOTE_IP? ОС - ubuntu.

Comment: 1. У вас должены быть удаленные хосты. 2. на удаленных хостах должен быть поднят rsync в режиме демона и описана шара куда будут литься файлы (+ возможно настройки безопасности, от кого эти файлы можно принимать и т.п.) 3. Под remote_ip имеется ввиду ip-адрес конкретного хоста из п.1

Comment: Демон rsync не обязателен, rsync вполне отлично бегает по ssh

Comment: @Мелкий, на сколько я знаю - ssh юзается в качестве бэкенда, шифрования и авторизации. Без демона rsync на той стороне работать не будет.

Comment: @donRumata ну я как-то активно юзаю. Демон никакой не настраивал и не запускал. Установлен пакет должен быть и локально и удалённо - это да. Но никаких демонов для работы не запущено.

Comment: @Мелкий, ну так или иначе - он всё равно запускается и там и там.